# Go shopping vs for shopping

Tags: prepositions, gerund-vs-infinitive

Yesterday I was teaching my student about the verb **shop**.  I told him that we use "go" with "shop"  to mean to go and buy things.
e. g.

> 1) You are going shopping.
>
> 2) You were going shopping.
>
> 3) You go shopping.
>
> 4) You went shopping yesterday.

Every thing was going well until I formed a question in this manner:

> "**Are you going to New York (insert any place here) to go
>   shopping?**"

I felt this sentence to be wrong.  Not grammatically but this is not how people ask.  As far I know,  this is how such question should be formed

> " **Are you going to New York for shopping**"

But again, I could be wrong.

Please tell me which one is correct and is used by the natives.

Answer (score 2):

*Are you going to New York to go shopping?* is grammatical, but the combination of *going*, *go* and *shopping* is not particularly felicitous. A more concise version is *Are you going to New York to shop?*

The grammaticality of *Are you going to New York for shopping* is questionable. You can make it grammatical by including the definite article:

- Are you going to New York for **the** shopping?

But this slightly changes the meaning to something like:

- Are going to New York because the shopping there is so good.

See, for example, the following headlines:

> *Come for the Shopping, Stay for the Food*
>
> https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/26/travel/shopping-in-store-restaurants.html
>
> *Forget turkey- tourists come to Vegas for the shopping*
>
> https://news3lv.com/news/local/forget-turkey-tourists-come-to-vegas-for-the-shopping

Comment: I don't really accept that "not particularly felicitous" bit. It's usually *learners* (not native speakers) who have a problem with "superficial repetition". The two elements *going **to** New York* and ***to** go shopping* serve completely different semantic and syntactic roles, and they're articulated differently anyway, so I wouldn't even *notice* them as being "similar" in speech. You don't need [to go to school to get an education](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+go+to+school+to+get+an+education%22) to know that's just "normal English".

Comment: I partly agree with what you say. I find "Are you going to New York to go shopping?" awkward, but "Are you going to New York just to go shopping?" sounds a whole lot better.  I think it's pragmatics; 'go shopping' is in a pretty convivial register, and your alternatives up-market the tone so as to avoid the incongruity.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. For me the slight infelicity is in the redundancy of the verb _go_ and as well the repetition of the _-ing_ verb form. How does _Are you going to town to go shopping?_ sound to you? It seems to me that the first _go_ (as in _going_) obviates the need for the second _go_.

Comment: Yeah, it did occur to me immediately *after* posting my comment that you were probably focusing on ***go*** rather than ***to***. Also that I was probably making too much of a minor point about stylistic choices. Whatever - noting that someone else has actually *downvoted* your answer, I think I'd better give it an uptick to redress the balance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Thanks. At the risk of belabouring the point, there is a similar redundancy in _I'm going to the river to go fishing_ or _I'm going to the Alps to go skiing_.

Comment: <concerned about going down a rabbit hole here> Whilst I agree that at first sight there seems to be an element of "redundancy" in *I'm going to the river to go fishing*, that can't really be right. After all, if anything there truly was redundant, that should imply we could express exactly the same thing using less words. But *I'm going to the river fishing* certainly doesn't work for me. On the other hand, I don't have a problem with *They're always going down the pub drinking*. Circumstances alter cases in ways that can't always be explained / rationalised.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. I see it as follows: The _go+ing_ expressions imply leaving the house and going (walking or travelling) to a place where the activity (fishing, skiing, etc.) can be pursued. So if the sentence already starts with "_I'm going_" then we have an unnecessary repetition. I agree that _I'm going to the river fishing_ does not work. A correct alternative is: _I'm going to the river to fish_; cf. _I'm going to the river to swim_.

Comment: Oops - wasn't thinking clearly! Yeah, you're quite right that *...to the river **to fish*** fits the bill without redundancy. I'm tempted to say that approach wouldn't work with *We're going to the fair to go on the Big Wheel*, but I know my brain isn't firing on all 4 cylinders today, so I'm probably wrong about that too. (We're definitely well into rabbit-hole territory though! :)